# Generic LINQ orderby lambda function

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I am wondering how the LINQ OrderBy is written? I tried to reproduce:

```
IOrderedQueryable<T> MyOrderBy<T,TKey>(IQueryable<T> qry, Expression<Func<T,TKey> expr)
{
  return qry.OrderBy(expr);
}
```

Which can be called as:

```
MyOrderBy<Products,String>(qry, p=>p.Name);
```

Refactoring this to an extension method into IQueryable, it can be called as:

```
qry.MyOrderBy<String>(p => p.Name );
```

which is not the same as the LINQ OrderBy, which needs no String type parameter. How to avoid that in my version?

ps: Object is not an alternative, as it won't work for Int32 and other Value type fields (along with EF Linq):

```
IOrderedQueryable<T> MyOrderByObject<T>(IQueryable<T> qry, Expression<Func<T,Object> expr)
{
  return qry.OrderBy(expr);
}
```

will drop an exception with (if ID is an Int32 field):

```
qry.MyOrderByObject(p => p.ID ); // throws an exception
```

Comment: hi, check this out, may help http://www.hookedonlinq.com/OrderByOperator.ashx

Comment: Throws *what* exception?

Comment: qry.MyOrderBy<String>(p => p.Name ); shouldn't work, since MyOrderBy takes 2 Type parameters.

Comment: James - An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll Additional information: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: "Object is not an alternative, as it won't work for Int32 and other Value type fields" Why not?

Comment: What makes your efforts different than calling `OrderBy` directly?

Comment: Gert - It is only the beginning. When I can call MyOrderBy properly, I can add other arguments as well, for example ordering directions, and MyOrderBy can choose between OrderBy and OrderByDescending... and so on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove **redundant type argument** in generic use of method.

In this case remove "String" type is right to continue, type of Name property (string) is recognized by compiler and not need to specify it;

Edit:

```
public static class MyExtentions
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> MyOrderBy<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> qry, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> expr)
    {
        return qry.OrderBy(expr);
    }
}
```

Call:

```
qry.MyOrderBy(p => p.Id)
```

Comment: @NicoSchertler that is true. Reza's answer works. Why should it not?

Comment: In this case what is the syntax to write and how to call this?

Comment: Thanks for the proper answer, it works. I wonder why?! :) What compiler feature supports this syntax? Is it documented somewhere? As far as I know this should have been called as `qry.MyOrderBy<String>(p => p.Name )`

Comment: @ZoltanHernyak, For more information in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx follow "type inference".